# How to get CheckBox "Ticked" inside ListBox on run time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, checkbox

I am creating windows phone 8 application, I have checkbox inside listbox, how do I get checkbox "CHECKED" when I click on checkbox?

I tried my best but not getting the result?
see my code below:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Width="429" Height="621" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,43,0,59" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Extended">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="440">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Height="30" TextAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Margin="5" Height="30" TextAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Favorite" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Height="30" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="344,-35,9,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" Height="72" Foreground="Black" IsChecked="False" Margin="353,-40,28,0" BorderBrush="Black" Loaded="CheckBox1_Loaded" Checked="CheckBox1_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox1_Unchecked"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
```

Here is my code behind file:

```
 private void CheckBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
        cb.IsChecked = true;
    }
```

Comment: What's actually not working? Your code seems fine (from a quick look at it). (Well, except for the part that you're setting IsChecked instead of getting it, but I guess you know you're doing that).

Comment: @yasen the problem is in designer view, in emulator I want checkBox "CHECKED" when I click on checkbox.

Comment: My question is can you see checkbox check but nothing happens or you don't even see that checkbox has any visual change? I mean for example the empty circle gets filled when you check it?

Comment: @Zgrkpnr yes, checkboxes remain empty even when I check on it,do  not get any visual change!thank you!!help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
 private void CheckBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CONTACTS data = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as CONTACTS;
        string contactId = data.contactId;
        string isFav = data.isFavourite.ToString();          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on emulator      in my listbox and it works fine. The textboxes checked and unchecked without any problem.

Comment: Apostolos, thank you for ur response, I have checkboxes in listbox, and still do not getting "Ticked" when click on it.can you post your code please??thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
        <ListBox.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush />
        </ListBox.BorderBrush>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

               <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Width="600" Padding="0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding Image}" Width="130" Height="130" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image.Clip>
                                    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" Rect="0,0,130,130" />
                                </Image.Clip>
                            </Image>
```

<--CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" Height="72" Foreground="Black" IsChecked="False" BorderBrush="Black"/-->

```
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
private void CheckBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CLASS_NAME item = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as CLASS_NAME;
        string id = item.Id;
        string name = item.Name;
    }
```